# Why are design questions or questions with multiple right answers being closed?

Tags: discussion

One of my [questions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5588/what-are-good-design-patterns-for-dynamic-visualforce-components-for-a-data-driv) is up for closing because (I assume) it is somewhat broad and there is not one unambiguously correct solution.

I'd like to discuss this as based on the upvotes there is clearly some disagreement about whether or not this is a good question.

Answer (score 4):

I would argue that the question should remain open because there are a number of questions in a similar vein ([asking for peoples thoughts on different approaches](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5570/better-performance-between-if-else-else-vs-hardcoded-maps), [asking for best practices around a language feature](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/431/what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-polymorphism-in-apex?rq=1), [asking for possible drawbacks to a certain approach](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4872/use-json-serialization-to-get-around-parameter-limitations-for-future-methods)) that had great answers that clearly add to the value of SFSE.

A great answer to my question would be something like:

> I've implemented something similar with dynamic components before and
>   it worked fairly well and was maintainable as I needed to extend/refactor the input form. You can do this with something like the following:
>
> $some sample vf and apex
>
> Make sure to to do $foo so you don't hit
>   $weird_dynamic_component_limitation down the line.

Even an answer that says:

> I tried to implement this with a similar approach and ran into issues: x,y,z. I think you would be better off sticking with dynamic vf bindings.

would be useful to me or someone coming along later who is considering the same question.

Comment: I agree, I do not think those questions are "too open". I think however, that they often cant be answered quickly or brief. They require a certain amount of expirience going through the same considerations in the past. It should be possible for a person to known pro&cons of possible approaches, compare them and post as an answer why a certain approach is preferable.

Comment: I think this kind of question would be great as a wiki, like the one I created on B2C options.

Answer (score 3):

I actually didn't vote to close your question.  I added that comment because the question had "best practices" in it and based on the previous discussion on meta I thought it would get closed, but thought that it had value.

I'm generally OK with those types of design questions and learn from them.  I think that whether or not  they are interpreted as questions that are soliciting discussions with no real answer has to do with how the questions are asked and/or certain words in them. I have no problem whatsoever with long questions and [long answers](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1362/development-team-best-practices-or-is-this-ide-for-real-i-am-in-disbelief/.), advantages/disadvantages to X vs. Y, etc.

Some are more clear cut then others as being acceptable (e.g., which of these 2 options is more efficient), but I am in favor of erring on the side of being inclusive.